# Sql left outer join with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing basically an e-commerce application. Application has two pages (all product and my-basket) authenticated user can add product to own basket. and I have three tables, the tables contains following data. I want to if the user adds product to own basket, these products don't exist on this user's all product page.

How should be the SQL query? I am looking query for all product page. so query's return type must be Product.

> If user added any products to own basket on all product page these products
>   shouldn't see on the all product page for this user.

```
PRODUCT TABLE    
+-------+--------+
|  id   | name   |
+-------+--------+
|  1    |   p1   |
|  2    |   p2   |
+-------+--------+

 USER TABLE
+-------+--------+
|  id   | name   |
+-------+--------+
|  3    |   U1   |
|  4    |   U2   |
+-------+--------+

BASKET TABLE
+-------+---------+-------------+
|  id   | fk_user | fk_product  |
+-------+---------+-------------+
|  5    |   3     |      1      |
|  6    |   4     |      2      |
+-------+---------+-------------+
```

So if authenticated user's id is *3*. The user should see *p2* product on own all product page.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (Perhaps some more sample data can be needed too.)

Comment: What query are you looking for? Do you want a query to return the products **viewable** by the user - i.e. the ones in the product table minus the ones in the user's basket?

Comment: I specified a sample result bottom of the question

Comment: Is BASKET TABLE the result?!? (You said there were three tables.)

Comment: Why would the fact a user has prodX in his basket, prevent you from still displaying ProdX in All Products ?

Comment: question re-edited sorry for missing information

Comment: Basket Table is unidirectional relationship table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT product.name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN basket ON basket.fk_product = product.id
WHERE (basket.fk_user != 3 OR basket.fk_user IS NULL)
```

Check my [demo query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5SDAT2eK1agKRuKckUyg79/0)

If you want you can also join the `user` table but with the data you gave me is not necessary.

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first (product) table plus all rows in the second (basket) table, when the on clause evaluates to `true`.

When the on clause evaluates to `false` or `NULL`, the `left join` still keeps all rows in the first table with `NULL` values for the second table.

Comment: Or simply `... LEFT JOIN basket ON basket.fk_product = product.id and basket.fk_user != 3`.

Comment: @jarlh Um, that doesn't sound right to me - but then again, neither does the accepted answer

Comment: @Strawberry, oops. My only intention was to simplify the query, not to answer the question.

Comment: @jarlh Ok, it's no biggie, but you didn't simplify the query. You provided a different query - one that generates a different result - just sayin'

Answer (score 2):

or, more commonly...

```
SELECT p.name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN basket b 
  on b.fk_product = p.id
AND b.fk_user = 3
WHERE b.fk_user is null
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM basket b
                  WHERE b.fk_product = f.id AND
                        b.fk_user = 3 
                 );
```

This seems like the most direct interpretation of your question.